# Bootstrap 3 NavBar brand text below image instead of beside it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just starting to refactor a site to use Bootstrap and I'm trying to get an image logo to be the first thing to the far left on the navbar and then next to it will be my menu. However using the code below it will display the logo where expected but the text "PBS" in the case is displayed below the image. Am I missing a css style? BTW, not sure if the server side hyperlink has anything to do with it but I'm using it because the homepage link will be different based on being logged in as a User or an Admin. I'm setting that link in the load of the masterpage.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlBrandLogo" CssClass="navbar-brand" runat="server"><img src="images/logo.png" /> PBS</asp:HyperLink>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you missed to make the both inline, It has nothing to do with bootstrap you can do it with below css

```
#hlBrandLogo 
{
  display:inline 
}    

img
{
  float:left;
}
```

try this and for ref [check](http://www.loriswebs.com/html-tips/verticallyalignimages.html), Hope this helps.

Comment: I just added the float left to the image and it looks like that works. Thanks.<img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left;" />